# AdehabitatLT and ltraj object: how to extract mean distance between relocations?

Tags: adehabitathr

I have an ltraj object , I would like to extract the mean distance  for day and the mean time  for day. The date is stored as `"("%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S")`, anyway I just need the relocations that occured during the same day. I have tried the function aggregate:

> a=aggregate(traj[[1]]$dist, by=list(traj[[1]]$date,"%d/%m/%Y"), FUN=mean)

I received the following error message:

> Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
>   arguments must have same length

I don't know how to ignore hour, minute and seconds and take in consideration just the year, month and day.